# How to display a select tag in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I had entered this tag in a `form.gsp` page in order to diplay a `select` but it doesn't work .Can you help me to find the error i have ?

```
    <div class="fieldcontain ${hasErrors(bean: userInstance, field: 'role', 'error')} required">
        <label for="role">
            <g:message code="user.role.label" default="Role" />
            <span class="required-indicator">*</span>
        </label>
        <g:select id="role" name="role.id" from="${taskmanagement1.secu.Role.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${userInstance?.role?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>        
    </div>
```

NB: I'm using Role & User domain classes generated by Spring Security .

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this, I didn't tested but think this will work

```
<g:select name="role.id" from="${taskmanagement1.secu.Role.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${userInstance.role*.id}" />
```